# Excel file corrupted on download to VBA App from .Net Website

Tags: .net, xml, vba

I have a VBA application that is talking to a .Net Web Page to download various files.  The code that I have to use within the VBA application is as follows: -

```
postDataString = "ID=" & SystemIdentificationCode & "&DevCode=" & ThisDeviceName & "&SysCode=" & SystemCode
For i = 0 To UBound(PostArray)
    postDataString = postDataString & "&f" & i & "=" & URLEncode(PostArray(i))
Next i

Set HTT = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
HTT.Open "Post", "http://" & IPAddress & ":" & PortAddress & "/CareControl/ShowDocument.ashx", False
HTT.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
'HTT.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/ms-excel"

HTT.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(postDataString)
HTT.sEnd postDataString

If HTT.Status = 200 Then

    outputObject = HTT.responseBody
    CallCloudForDocument = True
Else
    ErrorString = HTT.Status & ": " & HTT.statustext
    CallCloudForDocument = False
End If
Set HTT = Nothing
```

This code is connecting to a .Net website that I have also put together.

Now, when I use this code with a PDF or JPEG document it works fine.  The document is downloaded and I can write the output to a file.

When I try it with a Excel file, the object is corrupted.  My .Net code is also below: -

```
    Dim fInfo As New FileInfo(DocumentName)
    Dim numBytes As Long = fInfo.Length
    Dim fStream As New FileStream(DocumentName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

    Dim br As New BinaryReader(fStream)

    Dim DocData As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(CInt(numBytes))
    If DocExt = "xls" Or DocExt = "xlsx" Then
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
        context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Product_Report.xls")
    Else
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
    End If
'System.IO.File.WriteAllText(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("FileLogPath").ConnectionString, context.Response.ContentType)
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(DocData)
```

My thinking was that the corruption must be happening either on the .Net page or in the VBA App.  So to try and narrow it down I have set up a test rig using a .Net application.  This test rig calls the page, but uses .Net Web Client.  This works fine which indicates that the output from the .Net site is fine.  Test rig code below: -

```
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8

Dim responseArray As Byte() = webClient.UploadValues("http://192.168.1.64:/CareControl/ShowDocument.ashx", "POST", reqparm)

Dim newFile As FileStream = File.Create("C:\test54.xlsx")
newFile.Write(responseArray, 0, responseArray.GetLength(0))
newFile.Close()
newFile.Dispose()
```

So the issue must be in the VBA code.  But, this code works for PDF / Image files.

When I analyse to file, one generated by the VBA Code and one generated by the .Net test rig the only difference is in the very top of the file at the start, that looks like some spurious information inserted at the start of the file.

Any advice would be greatly received...

Comment: How is it corrupt? Have you looked inside the downloaded data for a mishandled server response?

Comment: I would use `application/vnd.ms-excel` as the mime type, particularly if your supporting .xls

Comment: You seem to force a .xls extension for .xlsx files

Comment: I have downloaded a HEX Editor and the corruption is in the first 13 words of the file.  The hex values are: - 11 20 01 00 15 22 00 00 00 00 00 00.  If I remove these and save the file it opens.  So, I have a very clunky work around (strip the first 13 words),but would love to know why this is being caused...

Comment: To answer your questions Alex K - the mime type you specified has been tried, but no joy.  Just to confirm, that the .Net test rig works fine which indicates that it is not the output from the .Net site.   I am only forcing the xls and xlsx extension in my test rig code.

Comment: How do you write outputObject to disk?

Answer (score 0):

The internet is a wonderful thing!  Found this article burried deep in it bowels: -
http://www.cknotes.com/vb6-variant-vs-byte-array/

The key paragraph is: - "There’s a mysterious extra 12 bytes prepended to the content that is saved. Why? Because you saved the Variant structure as well as the contents of the Variant"

So, used a byte array instead of a variant and bobs your uncle!!!