# Download xlsm files from sharepoint

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, download, xlsm

I am using the codes provided by [Solution to download sharepoint xlsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64352892/how-to-download-excel-file-from-my-sharepoint-com-onedrive)

It generates a file on my destination folder, but I am not able to use it. It seems to be corrupt.

Do I link the file to download wrongly?

Or is the issue an xlsm file for which the code was not designed?

```
Option Explicit
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
        ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
        ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
#End If

    Function DownloadFileFromWeb(strURL As String, strSavePath As String) As Long

        ' strSavePath includes filename
        DownloadFileFromWeb = URLDownloadToFile(0, strURL, strSavePath, 0, 0)
    End Function


Sub GetFile()
    Dim urlName  As String
    urlName = "https://talanx.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/LiabilityGlobalRisk/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7BC39E3D22-D263-4519-B6A5-33B64496F6E0%7D&file=Test.xlsm&action=default&mobileredirect=true"
    Dim fName As String
    fName = "J:\TEST\Test.xlsm"
    URLDownloadToFile 0, urlName, fName, 0, 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Web downloaded files are usually locked. Did you check that? (right click/properties)

Comment: If the file being "blocked" is the problem, and your next question is how to unblock it using VBA, you cannot, as that is protection from malicious files that people download.

Comment: Open the file with a text editor and see if it contains HTML and is not actually an Excel file.  The easiest way to fetch a file from SharePoint is to open it in excel and then save it to disk from there.